# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError CRFClassifier in a Rails app

Tags: ruby, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to run the CRFClassifier on a string to extract entities from the string. I'm using the Ruby bindings for the Stanford NLP entity recognizer from here: https://github.com/tiendung/ruby-nlp

It works perfectly fine on its own class say (nlp.rb). When I run `ruby nlp.rb` it works fine. However, I've tried to create an object of this class inside one of my controllers in my rails app and for some reason I'm getting the following error:

**`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/ie/crf/CRFClassifier`**

Here is the code that works fine on its own but not inside a controller.

```
    def initialize
        Rjb::load('stanford-postagger.jar:stanford-ner.jar', ['-Xmx200m'])
        crfclassifier = Rjb::import('edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier')
        maxentTagger = Rjb::import('edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger')
        maxentTagger.init("left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger")
        sentence = Rjb::import('edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Sentence')
        @classifier = crfclassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions("ner-eng-ie.crf-4-conll.ser.gz")


    end


    def get_entities(sentence)
        sent = sentence
        @classifier.testStringInlineXML( sent )

    end
```

It's the same exact code in both cases. Anyone has any idea of what's happening here!?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is stanford-postagger.jar? When you run nlp.rb is it in the same dir as the script? My suspicion is you need to provide the full path the jar file for the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

Rjb::load('/path/to/jar/stanford-postagger.jar:/path/to/jar/stanford-ner.jar', ['-Xmx200m'])

I just tried this and it works. Create a dir in lib called nlp. Put the jars there and then create a class which loads the jars using the full path:

So you end up with:

```
├── lib
│   ├── nlp
│   │   ├── stanford-ner.jar
│   │   └── stanford-postagger.jar
│   └── nlp.rb



require 'rjb'

class NLP
  def initialize
    pos_tagger = File.expand_path('../nlp/stanford-postagger.jar', __FILE__)
    ner = File.expand_path('../nlp/stanford-ner.jar', __FILE__)
    Rjb::load("#{pos_tagger}:#{ner}", ['-Xmx200m'])
    crfclassifier = Rjb::import('edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier')
    maxentTagger = Rjb::import('edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger')
    maxentTagger.init("left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger")
    sentence = Rjb::import('edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Sentence')
    @classifier = crfclassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions("ner-eng-ie.crf-4-conll.ser.gz")
  end


  def get_entities(sentence)
    sent = sentence
    @classifier.testStringInlineXML( sent )
  end
end
```

Little test class:

```
require_relative 'lib/nlp'

n = NLP.new
n.get_entities("Good afternoon Rajat Raina, how are you today?")
```

output:

```
ruby t.rb
Loading classifier from /Users/brendan/code/ruby/ruby-nlp/ner-eng-ie.crf-4-conll.ser.gz ... done [1.2 sec].
Getting data from Good afternoon Rajat Raina, how are you today? (default encoding)
Good afternoon <PERSON>Rajat Raina</PERSON>, how are you today?
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that but it doesn't work. I've also moved the jar files and the ser.gz file to the app/controllers directory and still doesn't work. In irb it works fine as well. Only inside my controller it does not work!

Comment: Are you sure you're using the full path? Just tried it and moved it lib to make it a little nicer and it works for me.

Comment: ok full path as in: /Users/username/railsappname/ that works fine. I didn't know I have to include the entire pwd path! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Either that or tell Rjb what the classpath is in your call to load. e.g. Rjb.load('/path/to/your/jar/files'), then load them using:   Rjb::add_jar(jar_name)